# Convert Crystal Reports to FastReport for Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports, converters, delphi-xe4, fastreport

My company just switched from using Delphi 2007 to Delphi XE4, and now we want to move from Crystal Reports to FastReport. However, we have over 200 reports that need to be converted. I know there was an "official" converter available on the FastReport website but it doesn't seem to be available for Delphi. Is there any other converting tool available to do that? Or is there a way to get my hands on the original mythical converter for Crystal to Fast Reports?

Comment: Wish I could say, we want to do the exact same, but have over 300 reports - the problem is we have so many custom screens that it will require a complete re-write for us.

Comment: I also faced a similar problem recently but with less that +-20 reports I ended up rewriting them for FastReport, I fear you might face a similar predicament

Answer (score 1):

You can download the FastReport converters from Fast Reports here:

http://www.fast-report.com/en/download/public_download/fr5.vcl/Converters.zip

It includes **RptToFr3.exe** which can do the conversion. I don't see any documentation outside of forum posts on the subject though.

The archive continues the following

- FastReport.Bars.dll
- FastReport.dll
- FastReport.Editor.dll
- FrxToFr3.exe
- RdlToFr3.exe
- RptToFr3.exe

You can find the documentation here:

https://www.fast-report.com/en/download/documentation/

Comment: Read about  RptToFr3.exe here: https://www.fast-report.com/en/forum/index.php?showtopic=11556